# How can I fill in a hole where a pond was that is attached to our patio?

Tags: patio

It's a long one but I'm hoping someone can help, please.

We had a  semi raised pond. We've dismantled it and are left with a hole about 4ft deep. We've broken up all the rubble from the sides of the pond to put in and the plan is to pave over it.

I have several questions.. 
1. Do I need to use a compactor to make it level before I pave it? I don't want to get subsidence, I plan to out the play house over the top.

2. Do I need to put anything in with the rubble such as sand or small hardcore?
3. I'm guessing I need to use a soft concrete for the slabs to enable drainage?
4. Why did I start this?!!

Any helpful advice will be greatly received, thanks.

Comment: drill a few large holes in the pond, and it should be fine.

Comment: A picture would help, please confirm it is a clay or poured concrete liner.

Comment: Does the hole drain now that the pond liner is gone? If not, you'll probably want to address that, too. Otherwise I'd get some sandy fill. Definitely want to compact it if you need to pave soon.